# What is the syntax for overloading the assignment operator (=) for a nested template class in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++

I am trying to overload an assignment operator in a cpp file for a nested template class.

My header file looks something like this:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Outer:
private:
   // some member variables
public:
   /*
   * Other functions here
   */

   template <class T>
   class Inner:
      Inner & Inner :: operator = (const Inner & rhs);
```

I can't, however, figure out what my cpp file should look like.
This is what I have:

```cpp
template <class T>
Outer<T>::Inner<T>:: Inner<T> & Inner<T> :: operator = (const Inner<T> & rhs)
{
   // code is here
}
```

This gives me the error:

> Iterator is not a template (C/C++ 864)

on the parts of my code surrounded by *

```
Outer<T>::Inner<T>::Inner<T> & **Inner<T>** :: operator = (const **Inner<T>** & rhs)
```

I would rather not make the operator overloads inline if I can avoid it. Help!

Comment: Trying to write definition of functions for template class declared in a header in cpp file looks strange. [c++ - Why can templates only be implemented in the header file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: `T` from `Inner` shadows `T` from `Outer`...

Answer (score 2):

Class template must be defined in header file. I am not sure to understand the question but the below code compile:

```
template <class T>
class Outer {
 public:
  template <class V>
  class Inner {
    Inner& operator=(const Inner& rhs);
};
};

template <class T>
template <class V>
Outer<T>::Inner<V>& Outer<T>::Inner<V>::operator=(const Outer<T>::Inner<V>& rhs) {
  //do something
   return *this;
}

int main() {
        Outer<int> o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Header File:

```cpp
template <class T>
class Outer
{
private:
   // some member variables
public:
   /*
   * Other functions here
   */

   class Inner
   {
   private:
      T t;
   public:
      Inner & operator = (const Inner & rhs);
   };
};
```

Working cpp file:

```cpp
template <class T>
Outer<T>::Inner & Outer<T>::Inner::operator = (const Inner & rhs)
{
   // code is here
}
```